# ManyToMany Query in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I can't get to work which should be so easy, reverse querying.
I looked at the documentation and at other examples on here but my "items" stays empty.

my models

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name','description')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

in my views I'm looking for all Items with the keyword:

```
def related(request, word):
    try:
        kw = Keyword.objects.get(name=word)
    except Keyword.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Keyword does not exist")
    items = kw.item_set.all()
    return render(request, 'index/related.html', {'items': items, 'kw': kw})
```

Querying an Item and using keywords.all() works fine, but the other way around not.

Comment: What result to you expect and what do get instead?

Comment: I expect a list of Items that have the same keyword but instead I get an empty list.

Comment: Is the data saved to the DB at that point?

Comment: I created the data with the admin interface, so there is data in the DB.

Comment: Use related name when you define ManyManyField e.g 
keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, related_name='all_items')

and then from the keywork object call `kw.all_items.all`
Hope this will help

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib a backwards relation is automatically created as class name in lowercase plus `_set`.

Comment: @KlausD. But it is good practice to define the related name always and i am not sure that in the ManytoMany relation the backward relation is defined automaticall, i haven't tried this before. But in OneToMany relation, yes the backward relation is defined automatically using _set.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib if there would be no `item_set`, there would be an error message.

Comment: I don't see any error in the code. You should test your queries manually on the console. Try running `manage.py shell_plus` and test your code.

Comment: @KlausD. yes so it is returning an empty list if there is something wrong here. Otherwise it will have a list of objects.

Comment: I take everything back... didn't do the migration before testing.